# Difference between "arrastrar" and "parar"

Tags: verbos, vocabulario-técnico

> El golpeteo de la puerta paró cuando me levanté aproximadamente a las 10
>   de la mañana para beber un vaso de agua.

Can I also use `arrastrar` in this context? What is the difference between `arrastrar` and `parar` ?

Comment: No existe la palabra *arrastar* en castellano. Otras que se escriben parecido son *arrestar* y *arrastrar*. ¿A cuál te refieres? De todas maneras, ninguna de ellas puede ser usada en lugar de *parar*.

Comment: It looks to me you are the victim of a _false friend_. There is a French verb _arrêter_ that means _to stop_ that seems to be the cause of the confusion. The Spanish word _arrestar_ means to arrest or detain a person which is also a way of _stopping_ them but likely not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrastrar` is not a synonym of `parar`.

> [Arrastrar](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/arrastrar) = To drag.

and

> [Parar](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/parar) = To stop.

If you are looking for a synomym for parar in your sentence, I would suggest:

> El golpeteo de la puerta cesó...
>
> El golpeteo de la puerta se detuvo...